# Windows embedded standard 7: Why won't keyboard filter appear in group policy? and can I add keyboard filter to OS without reinstalling WES7

Tags: operating-systems, group-policy, windows-embedded-7

I have an operating system image already created, all the features installed. 
For some reason keyboard filter does not appear in group policy editor, after I did add it to the distribution share and to the answer file used for the image.

Can I add it to the OS with out reinstalling? and why has it not appeared.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the issue sorted in the end thanks to : http://reboot.pro/topic/16383-windows-embedded-standard-7-add-packages-on-a-live-image/

You don't need to re-build the WES7 image from scratch.
Using 7-zip and the original WES7 ISO, you can extract only the CAB files that you want to add to the currently running WES7 OS (the live image).
All the Feature Packs and Drivers are located under DSpackages inside the WES7 ISO.

Some of the CAB files have a descriptive name that you may understand what feature-pack or driver they contain, but most names are more cryptic.
Opening the INF file inside the CAB can give you a better hint of what the package actually contains.

1. Extract the needed CAB files from the ISO and the place them on the live image, for example in C:Temp.
2. Open CMD with admin rights, and type:
   DISM.exe /online /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\Temp /NoRestart
3. All the CAB packages in C:\Temp will be installed. As you can see from the command syntax, there's no need to type each package name. It automatically searches for CAB files in the given path.
4. Now restart the machine and allow WES7 to perform the updates during shut-down and restart.

That's it.

NOTE: DISM.exe should already exist in C:\Windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64 (on the live image), so you can run the command directly from wherever the CMD window opened.